# How do I change the default repo path?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, ankhsvn

Every time I add a new Visual Studio solution to SVN via Ankh or Tortoise, it always gets added to the same folder that I do not want it added to.  I must have somehow changed a default path setting somewhere, but cannot locate it.

Also, is it possible to override the path before I do the commit?

Comment: I answered based on the limited info, but you might want to add more detail: If your filenames aren't confidential, you might want to provide both your local checkout dir listings and repo-browser screenshots.  Otherwise at least add less-vague descriptions of what you did, what you expect, and what happened

Answer (score 0):

When you svn-add inside an existing checkout, it will put it in your repo on the same relative location. If you have checked out the trunk of a trunk,tags,branches repo, and inside the trunk, you have a separate directory for each vb solution. When you svn-add to checkout\NewSolution and commit, I would expect it to end up in trunk\NewSolution, not in trunk\other\NewSolution.